# Meteor.js with react-router and alanning-roles

Tags: reactjs, meteor, meteor-accounts, meteor-react, alanning-roles

I am working on an application where I will be using two roles, admin and customers, which are basically users without roles.

I wrote the following code where I specify the routes I need and which pages should be authenticated. But when I check if the user has the admin role It always returns false, even though MongoDB shows that the user has the admin role (example is underneath the code).

What I wrote so far:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { Roles } from 'meteor/alanning:roles';

import React, { Component } from 'react';

import AuthenticationLayout from '../interface/layouts/authentication-layout';
import AdminLayout from '../interface/layouts/admin-layout';
import CustomerLayout from '../interface/layouts/customer-layout';

import NotFound from '../interface/pages/notfound';
import Login from '../interface/pages/login';
import SignUp from '../interface/pages/signup';

import AdminDashboard from '../interface/pages/admin/dashboard';
import CustomerOverview from '../interface/pages/admin/customers/customer-overview';
import ChatsOverview from '../interface/pages/admin/chats/chats-overview';
import LogsOverview from '../interface/pages/admin/logs/logs-overview';

import CustomerDashboard from '../interface/pages/customer/dashboard';

import SettingsOverview from '../interface/pages/admin/settings/settings-overview';
import RegistrationCardSettings from '../interface/pages/admin/settings/registration-cards';

const onEnterPublicPage = () => {
  if ( Meteor.userId() ) {
    browserHistory.replace('/klant');
  }
};
const onEnterPrivatePage = () => {
  if ( !Meteor.userId() ) {
    browserHistory.replace('/');
  }
};

const unauthenticatedPages = [ 
  '/', 
  '/login', 
  '/signup' 
];
const authenticatedPages = [ 
  '/admin',
  '/admin/klanten',
  '/admin/chats',
  '/admin/logboeken', 
  '/admin/instellingen',
  '/admin/instellingen/strippenkaart',
  '/klant'
];

export const onAuthChange = (isAuthenticated) => {
  Tracker.autorun(() => {
    const isAuthenticated = !!Meteor.userId();
    const pathname = browserHistory.getCurrentLocation().pathname;
    const isUnauthenticatedPage = unauthenticatedPages.includes(pathname);
    const isAuthenticatedPage = authenticatedPages.includes(pathname);

    const isAdmin = Roles.userIsInRole( Meteor.userId(), 'admin' );
    console.log(isAdmin); // always returns false..

    if (isUnauthenticatedPage && isAuthenticated) {
      browserHistory.replace('/klant');
    } else if (isAuthenticatedPage && isAuthenticated) {
      if( isAdmin ) {
        browserHistory.replace('/admin');
      } else {
        browserHistory.replace('/klant');
      }
    } else if (isAuthenticatedPage && !isAuthenticated) {
      browserHistory.replace('/');
    }
  });
};
export const routes = (
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route component={AuthenticationLayout}>
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route path="/" component={Login} onEnter={onEnterPublicPage} />
    </Route>
   <Route component={AdminLayout}>
    <Route path="/admin" component={AdminDashboard} onEnter={onEnterPrivatePage}/>
    <Route path="/admin/klanten" component={CustomerOverview} onEnter={onEnterPrivatePage}/>
    <Route path="/admin/chats" component={ChatsOverview} onEnter={onEnterPrivatePage}/>
    <Route path="/admin/logboeken" component={LogsOverview} onEnter={onEnterPrivatePage}/>
    <Route path="/admin/instellingen" component={SettingsOverview} onEnter={onEnterPrivatePage}/>
    <Route path="/admin/instellingen/strippenkaart" component={RegistrationCardSettings} onEnter={onEnterPrivatePage}/>
  </Route>

  <Route component={CustomerLayout}>
    <Route path="/klant" component={CustomerDashboard} onEnter={onEnterPrivatePage}/>
  </Route>

    <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp}/>
    <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
 </Router>
);
```

user with an admin role:
[image: correct roles for the user]
I first had the admin check outside the tracker,  but placing this inside the tracker did not do the trick unfortunately:

```
const isAdmin = Roles.userIsInRole( Meteor.userId(), 'admin' );
console.log(isAdmin); // always returns false..
```

Comment: Okay, I figured out that the routes work (a little) when I add the group ( default-group) on the check, like const isAdmin = Roles.userIsInRole( Meteor.userId(), ['admin'], default-group ); But now the redirect only works when I first land on the /klant route...

Comment: You have  Tracker.autorun(() => {}) inside definition of onAuthChange function. Are you executing onAuthChange somewhere in your code for the Tracker.autorun(() => {})  to get executed and start running code inside it anytime a reactive variable changes ? In the code given by you, there is no execution of onAuthChange. It was only defined.

Comment: I was executing the onAuthChange somewhere else. In the meantime I found out this was also an issue, causing my app to check the roles two times in a row which results in a flash of other pages before the final redirection. fixed it!